# Which combo has the highest DPS?

Tags: bayonetta-2

The different attacks seem to have different properties; some launch enemies up or away, or move you around the screen in different ways.

But if I just want to deal the most damage possible in a short amount of time, what combo is the best to use for that purpose? For example, I just dodged an attack and I have some free hits in witch time, and I just want to maximize my damage output against a boss. What combo should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I'll use the terminology P for Punch (X) and K for Kick (B).

Generally, you can fit a PKP in most Witch Times.  This seems like a pretty strong combo for most weapon combos.  It was very strong in the original, so I tend to default to PKP.

The amount of Witch Time you get seems to vary based on the enemy.  If you have more time, I like PPKP or PPPKP.
All of the above combos end with a Wicked Weave, meaning a chance to stagger the enemy. Which means more free hits!

PPPPP* (continue to mash P) and PPPPK* (continue to mash K) feel pretty good for damage as well, and are good for building combo hits.

Naturally, this will vary somewhat with the weapons you're using, but I've found these combos effective with the following weapons:
Hands: Default pistols, swords, whip
Feet: Default pistols, swords, whip